# Why some character is not showing in Dynamic Text field in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I set a Dynamic Text field parametrically in AS3.

If I set "**This is a test news**", it showing "**his is a test nes**"

Why it isn't showing some character?

Comment: what font you're using?

Comment: Default font @ cherniv

Answer (score 2):

You have to Embed the fonts that you are using for dynamic text. And select proper character range while embedding.

Answer (score -1):

This are happening because of font embedding. You have to use default font and will work. 
On my CS6 the first font are " _sans " and with this is working well...Good Luck